# How to expand an overflow-y div up to vertical available space?

Tags: css

I have a layout like this one:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="A"></div>
    <div id="B"></div>
    <div id="C"></div>
</div>
```

and here's the (incomplete) CSS:

```
#container {
    height: 400px;
    background: red;    
}

#A {
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;
}

#B {
    height: 300px;
    background: blue;
    overflow-y: auto;    
}

#C {
    height: 50px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

So A B and C should be stacked on top of each other, and B should fill the remaining space between A and C, showing a scroll bar if its content is too much.
My problem is that sometimes C **may be missing**, how can I make B expand dynamically to take its space too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is:

```css
#B:last-child {
    height: 350px;
}​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/7Bqkb/1/

So, if `#B` is the last child, manually set the height to the correct value.

[`:last-child` browser support.](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3)

Comment: If the lack of IE7/8 support is a problem, this idea can be restructured to work in even those browsers.

Comment: Well IE8 support wouldn't be bad :)

Comment: I'm sure I had an easy fix in mind, but I can't for the life of me remember what it was... here's a less than elegant fix involving swapping the order of your HTML slightly: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/7Bqkb/

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is using the `~` selector:

```
#B {
    height: 350px;
    background: blue;
    overflow-y: auto;    
}
#C~#B {
    height: 300px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VtWAY/2

Should have IE7+ support http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/generalsiblingselector

Edit: Only works if you also swap B and C in the html. http://jsfiddle.net/VtWAY/4/

Comment: Unfortunately `#C~#B { height: 300px; }` won't do anything with that HTML: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/VtWAY/3/. You can see that `#B` is still 350px high if you scroll down. Inside the reference link you posted, read near the "has to occur before" part.

Comment: Oops... I was sure it worked for me sometime in the past. Guess not, sorry. Of course, it works if you swap the order of `B` and `C`.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't swap them :( As always, IE makes people waste a lot of time... *Sigh*

Comment: So I guess it's either adding a class to B when C is not there, or using javascript.